Razorpay Payment Page Goes Blank After Entering Card Details and Completing Bank Page
I have a Chrome extension installed in my browser. When I try to make a payment on a website using Razorpay, the process works fine until the final step. Here's what happens:
After entering the card details, it redirects me to the bank page for authentication (e.g., OTP or 3D Secure).
Once the bank authentication is complete, it tries to load the following URL:
https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/PQbvIYLStZWZzw/authenticate
Instead of completing the payment process, this page turns blank.
I’ve noticed that this issue occurs only when my Chrome extension is enabled. When I disable the extension, the payment process works as expected.
How can I resolve this issue while keeping my extension enabled?
I’ve already tried the following to resolve the issue:
Excluding Razorpay URLs in the manifest file:
I updated my manifest.json to exclude Razorpay-related URLs to prevent my extension from injecting content scripts on these pages. Here’s the code I used in the content_scripts section of my manifest:
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "exclude_matches": ["*://*.razorpay.com/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
]

Despite this change, the issue persists.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Perhaps use the Dev Toolbox console (whatever the Chrome feature is called) to show what is being sent.  Other than that, you need to see how your extension is interacting with the payment process.

Did you reload the extension in chrome://extensions page after editing? Do you use host_permissions and chrome.scripting? If so, show the code.

@woxxom,
Yes, I have host_permissions in my manifest.json. Here are the relevant permissions:
"host_permissions": [
"<all_urls>",
"https:///",
"http:///"
]
Regarding chrome.scripting, I am not using it in my code. Instead, I am using chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(changeUrlHandler) in the background.ts file to handle URL changes.
I hope this helps clarify!

Since you don't use chrome.scripting to run scripts on that site, it sounds like a bug in Chrome.

ohh, @woxxom sorry i have checked it again i found that i am using chrome.scripting in my service-worker(background.ts) file and bellow is the code of it
chrome.scripting.executeScript(
{
target: { tabId: tab.id },
func: () => localStorage.getItem("token")
},
(result) => {
      token = result[0].result;
      
    });


Well then make sure you don't run it on those URLs.
